# javascript toggle div style display by button

Tags: javascript

hey i was wondering if someone could help me work out why my function to change the style display by className is not working it works for the one's with ID's but does not work using class?

also wondering if there is away i could change the button class onclick from btn-red to btn-green using javascript only?

```js
window.toggleDisplayByID = function(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == null || e.style.display == "none") {
    e.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    e.style.display = "none";
  }
}

window.toggleDisplayByClass = function(className) {
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  if (c.style.display == null || c.style.display == "none") {
    c.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    c.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #444;
  color: #eee;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:active {
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-green {
  background-color: #47950d;
}

.btn-green:hover,
.btn-green:active {
  background-color: #64b820;
}

.btn-red {
  background-color: #b3353c;
}

.btn-red:hover,
.btn-red:active {
  background-color: #cb575b;
}
```

```html
<button id="display1" class="btn btn-red" onclick="toggleDisplayByID('hud-popup-overlay')">Toggle div 1</button>
<button id="display2" class="btn btn-red" onclick="toggleDisplayByID('hud-leaderboard')">Toggle div 2</button>
<button id="display3" class="btn btn-red" onclick="toggleDisplayByClass('hud-bottom-righ')">Toggle div 3</button>
<button id="display4" class="btn btn-red" onclick="toggleDisplayByClass('hud-bottom-left')">Toggle div 4</button>

<div id="hud-popup-overlay">
  <p>
    Something Here 1
  </p>
</div>

<div id="hud-leaderboard">
  <p>
    Something Here 2
  </p>
</div>

<div class="hud-bottom-righ">
  <p>
    Something Here 3
  </p>
</div>

<div class="hud-bottom-left">
  <p>
    Something Here 4
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of elements, you will need to loop/iterate through the node list/collection the clue is in getElement**S**

Comment: getElementById is one Element but getElementsByClassName are multiple Elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- Your class name for the fourth element was incorrect in HTML
- There was an undefined variable inside your second function

You are not dealing with a single element when you `getElementsByClassName()`. Loop through the list and set your style.

I changed toggleDisplayById and toggleDisplayByClass parameters so it can include the element id of the buttons. Inside each of those functions, They get the button element by:

```
var b = document.getElementById(btnId);
```

Also, I created a helper function that removes and add the styles:

```
function removeAndAddClass(element,removeClass,addClass){
    element.classList.remove(removeClass);
    element.classList.add(addClass);
 }
```

```js
window.toggleDisplayByID = function(btnId,id) {

      var e = document.getElementById(id);
      var b = document.getElementById(btnId);
      if (e.style.display == null || e.style.display == "none") {
        e.style.display = "block";
        removeAndAddClass(b,'btn-green','btn-red');
      } else {
        e.style.display = "none";
        removeAndAddClass(b,'btn-red','btn-green');
      }
    }

    window.toggleDisplayByClass = function(btnId,className) {
      var c2 = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(className));            
      var b = document.getElementById(btnId);
      
      if(b.classList.contains('btn-red')){
        removeAndAddClass(b,'btn-red','btn-green');
      }else{
        removeAndAddClass(b,'btn-green','btn-red');
      }
      c2.forEach(c => {
        if (c.style.display == null || c.style.display == "none") {
          c.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          c.style.display = "none";
        }
      });
    }
 function removeAndAddClass(element,removeClass,addClass){
    element.classList.remove(removeClass);
    element.classList.add(addClass);
 }
```

```css
  .btn {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 40px;
      padding: 0 20px;
      background: #444;
      color: #eee;
      border: 0;
      font-size: 14px;
      vertical-align: top;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      border-radius: 4px;
      transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    }

    .btn:hover,
    .btn:active {
      background-color: #555;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .btn-green {
      background-color: #47950d;
    }

    .btn-green:hover,
    .btn-green:active {
      background-color: #64b820;
    }

    .btn-red {
      background-color: #b3353c;
    }

    .btn-red:hover,
    .btn-red:active {
      background-color: #cb575b;
    }
```

```html
    <button id="display1" class="btn btn-red" onclick="toggleDisplayByID('display1','hud-popup-overlay')">Toggle div 1</button>
    <button id="display2" class="btn btn-red" onclick="toggleDisplayByID('display2','hud-leaderboard')">Toggle div 2</button>
    <button id="display3" class="btn btn-red" onclick="toggleDisplayByClass('display3','hud-bottom-righ')">Toggle div 3</button>
    <button id="display4" class="btn btn-red" onclick="toggleDisplayByClass('display4','hud-bottom-left')">Toggle div 4</button>

    <div id="hud-popup-overlay">
      <p>
        Something Here 1
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="hud-leaderboard">
      <p>
        Something Here 2
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="hud-bottom-righ">
      <p>
        Something Here 3
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="hud-bottom-left">
      <p>
        Something Here 4
      </p>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object, so you would have to index it.

```
window.toggleDisplayByID = function(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == null || e.style.display == "none") {
    e.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    e.style.display = "none";
  }
}

window.toggleDisplayByClass = function(className) {
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  c.forEach(function(x) {
      if (x.style.display == null || x.style.display == "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As for your first question, it doesn’t work because `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, so you have to *iterate* over them.